# Select 2 other fields in one query with other conditions

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I got this query:

```
SELECT `u`.`name`, `items`.* 
FROM `users` `u`, `items` 
WHERE `u`.`id` = `items`.`ownerid` AND `item_name` LIKE ?
```

It is working fine, but I need to modify it so it'll:

- Withdraw what it withdraws right now.
- +withdraw `items`.`id` in one rows and `items`.`id` `WHERE` `items`.`add` `> 0` in another row.
  So I'll get `item.id` in one column (original) and in the second column `item.id` with the above condition.

Comment: Please post some example data and the query result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a [`case statement`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html), which'll return a column based on whatever conditions you want.

```
select u.name
     , i.id
     , case i.add when 0 then null else i.id end
     , items.*
  from users u
     , items i
 where u.ud = i.ownerid
   and item_name like ?
```

Comment: Getting this message: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'case , i.* from users u , items i where u.id = i.ownedid ' at line 3`

Comment: @Rym sorry, my fault. I've been using PL\SQL a lot recently. I've changed the syntax in the answer.

Comment: No problem. Here comes another message:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select null else select i.id end case , i.* from users u , items ' at line 3`

Comment: Ach @Rym, I hate my(sql) sometimes, try getting rid of the interior selects in the case statement, which should hopefully work. What version are you on?

Comment: @Rym I'm a fool, you don't need the `end case` if you're doing it in a select only a function / procedure. It should just be `end`, so: `case i.add when 0 then null else i.id end`. Hopefully :-).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4124/discussion-between-ben-and-rym)